# Determine installation of the app from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, installation, mobile-application

I am using in my app Facebook's Mobile App Ads for Installs.
That means I can see when people install my app **from Facebook** along with the conversion rates using Facebook's dashboard.

My question:
Is there a way to know that from code?
I mean, is there a way to know when the user installed and launched the app **from Facebook** versus installed and launched from the App Store?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd go with No on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the public iOS APIs the answer is definitely No. You can only catch if your app is launched from a push notification.

A workaround is to create a URL scheme and track the events on your own (when this scheme is called). The official documentation for this is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18).

Comment: Thanks! I just don't understand how URL Scheme can help in such a case. When an application is installed via Facebook and then launched from the Springboard, the URL Scheme is not called, is it?

Comment: No it is not called then. URL schemes are helpful if you want to launch your app from another application. They cannot tell you the installation source.